# First Unique Number Slow runtime issue

Tags: c++, list, stl, queue, unordered-map

So I recently implemented "First unique number" on Leetcode. The question, for reference, goes something like this:

You have a queue of integers, you need to retrieve the first unique integer in the queue.

Implement the FirstUnique class:

- FirstUnique(int[] nums) Initializes the object with the numbers in
  the queue.
- int showFirstUnique() returns the value of the first unique integer of the queue, and returns -1 if there is no such integer.
- void add(int value) insert value to the queue.

My C++ implementation using STL uses an unordered_map and a list. The map stores the elements of the queue as keys and stores the iterator pointing to the element in the list and a boolean indicating to indicate the removal of the value from the list when it is no longer unique. The addition and removal of elements to the list appear to be constant time operations. However, my solution is much slower compared to another solution which uses a queue and iterates through the queue (basically it appears to be O(n) compared to my O(1)).

Here is the apparently worse solution:

```
class FirstUnique {
        private:
        queue<int> q;
        unordered_map<int, int> count;
        public:
        FirstUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
            for(int num: nums){
                count[num]++;
                q.push(num);
            }
        }

        int showFirstUnique() {
            while(!q.empty() && count[q.front()] > 1){
                q.pop();
            }
            if(q.empty()){
                return -1;
            }
            else{
                return q.front();
            }
        }

        void add(int value) {
            if(++count[value] == 1){
                q.push(value);
            }
        }
    };
```

This is my solution:

```
class FirstUnique {
    public:
    unordered_map<int, pair<list<int>::iterator, bool>> hashmap;
    list<int> l;
    FirstUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
    for(auto it=nums.begin(); it!=nums.end(); it++)
        add(*it);
    }

    int showFirstUnique() {
        if (l.empty())
            return -1;
        return l.back();
    }

    void add(int value) {
        unordered_map<int, pair<list<int>::iterator, bool>>::iterator it = hashmap.find(value);
        if(it == hashmap.end())
        {
            l.push_front(value);
            hashmap[value] = make_pair(l.begin(), false) ;
        }

        else
        {
            if((it->second).second == false)
            {
                l.erase((it->second).first);
                (it->second).second = true;
            }
        } 
    }
 };
```

What I don't understand is that despite my fast solution, the runtime is much slower. The one with the queue ran in 328ms and mine ran in 532ms on Leetcode. I can understand my solution being memory heavy but can't understand why it is slower.

Comment: `hashmap.find()` is linear in complexity (worst-case). In addition, constant-time isn't always faster than O(n), it depends on n most of the time (iterating over a small array might be faster than indexing into a hashmap containing the same number of elements). This means that if your `add` method is used during the timed run, it wouldn't be that surprising for your solution to be somewhat slower.

Answer (score 1):

We need to only push unique values to the list. For tracking of the unique values, create an unordered map of which keeps track of unique value.

```
public:
    list<int> li;
    unordered_map<int, bool> m;
    FirstUnique(vector<int>& nums) {
        for(auto i:nums){

//         if i is not in map then we push i to the list an make m[i] = true i.e. unique
//         else we make it false. i.e. it is not unique now. 

            if(m.find(i) == m.end()){
                li.push_back(i);
                m[i] = true;
            }else{
                m[i] = false;
            }
        }

    }

    int showFirstUnique() {
        for(auto it:li){
            if(m[it] == true){
                return it;
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }

    void add(int value) {
        if(m.find(value) == m.end()){
            li.push_back(value);
            m[value] = true;
        }else{
            m[value] = false; 
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We need only LinkedHashMap in Java.  Which will keep track of the orders of the items received. In the constructor, we will just mark the number which are unique.
Same thing to be done in the add method.
In the showFirstUnique, we will just iterate through the map and return the one which is marked as unique. Please see the below code for more clarity.

```
class FirstUnique {
Map<Integer, Integer> map;

public FirstUnique(int[] nums) {
    map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int num : nums) {
        if (map.containsKey(num)) {
            map.put(num, 0);
        } else {
            map.put(num, 1);
        }
    }
}

public int showFirstUnique() {
    for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(key) == 1) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public void add(int value) {
    if (map.containsKey(value)) {
        map.put(value, 0);
    } else {
        map.put(value, 1);
    }
}
}
```